# How to access different culture resources in other dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, resources

I  have two projects, resource project that only keeps the resources and the actual working project, which is a console class or web service using C#.net

The resource project generates the following dlls:

```
+folder "de":
ExportService.SharedResources.resources.dll
+folder "en-US":
ExportService.SharedResources.resources.dll
+folder "fr":
ExportService.SharedResources.resources.dll
+folder "id":
ExportService.SharedResources.resources.dll
+folder "ja":
ExportService.SharedResources.resources.dll
+folder "zh-CN":
ExportService.SharedResources.resources.dll

and lastly ExportService.SharedResources.dll in root bin directory
```

the console/web service project need to use these dlls depending on a cultureInfo varible

so far I use

```
ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo, true, true) and 
ResourceManager.GetString(key, CultureInfo)
```

they always give me English.

Do I need to load one of these dlls on my own?

how to do it then?